# Is there an effective way to assert an constexpr-if branch is executed?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17, compile-time, if-constexpr

```
int f(auto obj) {
    if constexpr (HasFastGetData<decltype(obj)>) {
        return obj.FastGetData();
    } else {
        return obj.GetData();
    }
}

int main() {
    B obj;
    f(obj);
    // How to verify obj.FastGetData(), rather than obj.GetData(), is executed?
}
```

Take the code above as an example:

- I have two classes `A` & `B`.
- `A` has a member function `int GetData()` and `B` has a member function `int FastGetData()`.
- The two functions have the same symantics, but `FastGetData` is faster than `GetData`.
- I want `f` to differentiate the types of obj for better performance.

I just wonder:

**Is there an effective way to unit test my intent?**

Comment: The `if constexpr` condition is exactly what you want to assert, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I just want to verify my intent is fulfilled by `f`.

Comment: What I mean is, don't you simply want to add `static_assert(HasFastGetData<B>);`? A unit test can't test this, because it isn't part of observable behavior.

Comment: You're testing your implementation instead of the interface, so no, there isn't.

Comment: Just return a say `std::pair` containing the status code.

Comment: Even if the first branch will never be executed, the result is correct. I want to have an automatical testing.

Comment: @user12002570, that will pollute the clean interface.

Comment: @xmllmx What kind of mistake do you intent to catch with the test? If you add `static_assert(HasFastGetData<B>);` after `f(B)`, then, as long as `f`'s declaration and the `if constexpr` condition isn't changed, the language guarantees you that the branch you want is taken, i.e. if someone removed/forgets the `FastGetData` member function the compiler will tell you. But I am not sure that is the failure case you have in mind. I am not even sure whether you are intending to test `f` or `B`...

Comment: @xmllmx I mentioned a possible way of achieving what you want. It may have some disadvantages as all things do.

Comment: take a step back, what is your true intent. "`f` calls only the GetFastData` flow if and only if some trait" then it's trivial by mocking, "`f` call is constexpr whenever `obj` supports fast data" then you should do templated function calls. We would assume both `GetData`  calls have side effects hence are not `constexpr`, but that might not be your case.

Comment: There is no reason to test this in the final executable. Make a unit test, and two objects one that supports fast data and one that does not. Call f with both of them and verify it compiles and the correct method gets called in your test. And you are done... IMO you should not even write code without unit tests at all

Comment: @user12002570 NO do not recommend std::pair! It is intended to be used in template programming in almost ALL other cases it is better to declare a struct with two member variables with readable names

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, that is why I have explicitly said that they can also create a struct with sensible named members in my answer.

Comment: What do you want to test? `HasFastGetData<B>` is true, or if `HasFastGetData<T>` is true, then `obj.FastGetData()` is called? `static_assert`handle the proper, mock test handles the later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add  `static_assert(HasFastGetData<B>)` after the call to `f` or return a `std::pair` containing the result:

**Method 1**

```
f(obj);
//------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--->condition of first branch goes here
static_assert(HasFastGetData<B>); //this makes sure that the first branch if taken
```

---

**Method 2**

You can also return a `std::pair`(or a custom struct with sensible named members) to check:

```
std::pair<int,int> f(auto obj) {
    if constexpr (HasFastGetData<decltype(obj)>) {
        return {1, obj.FastGetData()};
    } else {
        return {0,obj.GetData()};
    }
}
int main() {
    B obj;
    std::pair<int, int> result = f(obj);
    if(result.first){} //first branch taken
    else{} 
    
}
```

Comment: In Method2 you modifiy the function under test which I think is not a good idea. (Consider std::optional i.o. std::pair)

Answer (score -2):

You can use GoogleTest, assert an EXPECT_CALL to the function FastGetData().

Comment: I think you are get downvoted for not providing an code example. I agree with your basic idea.. this just requires a unit test.